# PHP Cannot redeclare class

Tags: php, math

I found out my previous code (from my previous question) was too slow to do what I wanted so now I have a fast working code. I added a simple code to count. As for Cannot redeclare class, I have read other questions which involve referring to a .php file like require_once(something.php) I don't have any other files except this. I tried setting up two files so I do have a .php file but then I get multiple errors. Here's my code.

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set("display_errors", 1);
ini_set("log_errors", 0);

$numbers = 0;
$amout = 0;

while ($numbers < 50) {
    $numbers + 1;

// This till end of class is to get the divisor numbers
class Divisors {
  public $factor = array();

  public function __construct($num) {
    $this->num = $num;
  }

  // count number of divisors of a number
  public function countDivisors() {
    if ($this->num == 1) return 1;

    $this->_primefactors();

    $array_primes = array_count_values($this->factor);
    $divisors = 1;
    foreach($array_primes as $power) {
      $divisors *= ++$power;
    }
    return $divisors;
  }

  // prime factors decomposer
  private function _primefactors() {
    $this->factor = array();
    $run = true;
    while($run && @$this->factor[0] != $this->num) {
      $run = $this->_getFactors();
    }
  }

  // get all factors of the number
  private function _getFactors() {
    if($this->num == 1) {
      return ;
    }
    $root = ceil(sqrt($this->num)) + 1;
    $i = 2;
    while($i <= $root) {
      if($this->num % $i == 0) {
        $this->factor[] = $i;
        $this->num = $this->num / $i;
        return true;
      }
      $i++;
    }
    $this->factor[] = $this->num;
    return false;
  }
} // our class ends here

$example = new Divisors($numbers);
// Here it will check if the divisor has 5 divisors
if ($example->countDivisors() == 5) {
    // if true it will add 1 to the amount of numbers with 5 divisors
    $amount + 1;
}
}
// when the loop has checked 50 numbers it will print the amount
if ($numbers == 50){
    print "There are $amount numbers with 5 divisors";
}
?>
```

How would I fix this? (and second is the code which is not the class valid?)

Comment: Your class is inside the `while` loop so it re-declares each time through the loop.  Move it out.

Comment: Using some simple code indentation would have highlighted this quite quickly

Comment: When moving it out I get; syntax error, unexpected 'while' (T_WHILE), expecting function (T_FUNCTION)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your class is declared within a `while` loop, and it gets re-declared every iteration.

What you probably meant, is to make a new instance of it every iteration.

This is the modified code

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set("display_errors", 1);
ini_set("log_errors", 0);

// This till end of class is to get the divisor numbers
class Divisors
{
  public $factor = array();

  public function __construct($num) {
    $this->num = $num;
  }

  // count number of divisors of a number
  public function countDivisors() {
    if ($this->num == 1) return 1;

    $this->_primefactors();

    $array_primes = array_count_values($this->factor);
    $divisors = 1;
    foreach($array_primes as $power) {
      $divisors *= ++$power;
    }
    return $divisors;
  }

  // prime factors decomposer
  private function _primefactors() {
    $this->factor = array();
    $run = true;
    while($run && @$this->factor[0] != $this->num) {
      $run = $this->_getFactors();
    }
  }

  // get all factors of the number
  private function _getFactors() {
    if($this->num == 1) {
      return ;
    }
    $root = ceil(sqrt($this->num)) + 1;
    $i = 2;
    while($i <= $root) {
      if($this->num % $i == 0) {
        $this->factor[] = $i;
        $this->num = $this->num / $i;
        return true;
      }
      $i++;
    }
    $this->factor[] = $this->num;
    return false;
  }
} // our class ends here

$numbers = 0;
$amout = 0;

while ($numbers < 50)
{
    $numbers + 1;

    $example = new Divisors($numbers);
    // Here it will check if the divisor has 5 divisors
    if ($example->countDivisors() == 5) {
        // if true it will add 1 to the amount of numbers with 5 divisors
        $amount + 1;
    }
}
// when the loop has checked 50 numbers it will print the amount
if ($numbers == 50){
    print "There are $amount numbers with 5 divisors";
}
?>
```